# Angular2: Unexpected directive value 'undefined' on the View of component 'AppComponent'

Tags: angularjs

Here is [the git project](https://github.com/luozt/fis3-angular2-app.git).

I copied most of the code of [Angular 2 Seed](https://github.com/mgechev/angular2-seed), but a different result came out.

Mine threw an error of `Unexpected directive value 'undefined' on the View of component 'AppComponent'`, but I had checked the code, it seems no such a problem.

I just couldn't find the bugs, need your help. Just clone the project, and run `npm i`, `npm start`.

Answer (score 0):

I had figured out that, it was because I imported an undefined component as directive, so it threw an error of "Unexpected directive value 'undefined' on the View of component 'AppComponent'".

So, check your code! Even though your code can be the same to a tutorial, you may still import a component of undefined.